# Docker-machine cannot connect to default machine (Windows)

Tags: windows, docker, virtualbox, docker-machine

I have problem with using docker-machine after windows update on my Windows 8.1 Enterprise.
I'm using Docker Toolbox 1.12.5. I can run docker with no problem, but after windows update docker-machine cannot connect to default machine.
I can see in VirtualBox that default machine is running, but when I tried to run

```
docker-machine env default
```

it gave me "Error checking TLS connection: Host is not running".

When I run

```
docker-machine ls
```

I get:

```
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL   SWARM   DOCKER   ERRORS
default            virtualbox   Timeout
```

I found some suggestions to restart default machine so I ran

```
docker-machine restart default
```

but it always gives me following error:

```
 Restarting "default"...
Starting "default"...
(default) Check network to re-create if needed...
Error setting up host only network on machine start: C:\Program Files\Oracle\Vir
tualBox\VBoxManage.exe modifyvm default --nic2 hostonly --nictype2 82540EM --nic
promisc2 deny --hostonlyadapter2 VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter --cableco
nnected2 on failed:
VBoxManage.exe: error: Code E_FAIL (0x80004005) - Unspecified error (extended in
fo not available)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "LockMachine(a->session, LockType_Write)" at lin
e 507 of file VBoxManageModifyVM.cpp
```

I tried solutions suggested on :
https://www.bountysource.com/issues/29373416-vboxmanage-exe-error-context-lockmachine-a-session-locktype_write-at-line-493-of-file-vboxmanagemodifyvm-cpp
and https://github.com/docker/toolbox/issues/360 without success.

I would really appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try restarting your system and then check?

Docker has released Community and Enterprise edition for docker. I would recommend you to upgrade to community edition and recreate your default machine using below command. They claim to have fixed some bugs in these editions.

`docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default`

you can add more parameters to above command if you want.